# Using MS SQL Server Analysis Services to create cubes on hierarchical data

Tags: sql-server-2008, data-warehouse, ssas

I have a hierarchy, like an ProductDimension hierarchy.  Currently, I query this table using the [Nested Sets methodology](http://www.developersdex.com/gurus/articles/112.asp).  I write the usual star-schema joins to get a time-series report of groups of Products (Batches, CountryOfOrigin, ProductLine, etc.).

I'm currently investigating using SSAS cubes- but can a cube model this?

Are there any resources that would help with the creation of a cube based on hierarchies?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good use for a parent-child relationship in a dimension?

Like the standard Employee dimension, where each employee is 'beneath' their boss in the hierarchy. A quick example is here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174846.aspx

> In this dimension table, the
>   ParentOrganizationKey column has a
>   foreign key relationship with the
>   OrganizationKey primary key column. In
>   other words, each record in this table
>   can be related through a parent-child
>   relationship with another record in
>   the table. This kind of self-join is
>   generally used to represent
>   organization entity data, such as the
>   management structure of employees in a
>   department.